# OCUnit testing problems in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, ocunit

I create single view application with 1) Story board 2) ARC and 3) Unit Testing.
In view controller i drag on UIButton. and ViewContrller embedded with Navigation Controller (Using Interface).
It run fine in when i simply run the application, But when i run the application test case target then it aries problem.

[image]

vc is ViewController Object which i declare in .h file. and createPDFBtn is the object of UIButton.

Which thing i missing?

Comment: could you please post the .h file of your vc ViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `createPDFBtn` on your view controller (`self.vc`). Since you do not have a method with this name you get an error message:

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

Three possible problems and their solutions:

- You may be calling the method on the wrong object - is `vc` your right object?
- `vc` is correct but you do not have the `createPDFBtn` method implemented - implement the method.
- you have implementet `createPDFBtn` in your `vc` object - is it a public or a private method? Is it in your .h file ?

Comment: please modify your answer, I modify my question.